# ListBoxItem templated without ContentPresenter?

Tags: wpf, contentpresenter

Is it possible to template a ListBoxItem so that in the visual tree the ContentPresenter is left out and I have direcctly the data template underneath the ListBoxItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace the ListBoxItem Style by one that does not have a ContentPresenter, like this very basic one:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

For a more realistic Style you may copy the default ListBoxItem Style from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and replace the ContentPresenter by something that fits your needs.

Comment: When I use such a template the DataTemplates are not applied to the items.

Comment: Of course they aren't, because that is exactly why there is a ContentPresenter. When an items container (e.g. a ListBoxItem) is prepared for displaying a data item, the `ItemTemplate` of the ItemsControl (e.g. ListBox) is applied to the `ContentTemplate` property of the ContentPresenter. Please see the Remarks section in the [ItemTemplate MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.